# How to sort list of dicts in js?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

How to sort list of dicts in js?

I have:

```
[{'car': 'UAZ', 'price': 30 ,'currency': 'RUB'}, {'car': 'Mazda', 'price': 1000 ,'currency': 'USD'},{'car': 'Zaporozhec', 'price': 2 ,'currency': 'RUB'}, {'car': 'GAZ', 'price': 0 ,'currency': 'RUB'}]
```

I want to have it sorted by price and currency:

```
[{'car': 'Mazda', 'price': 1000 ,'currency': 'USD'}, {'car': 'UAZ', 'price': 30 ,'currency': 'RUB'},{'car': 'Zaporozhec', 'price': 2 ,'currency': 'RUB'}, {'car': 'GAZ', 'price': 0 ,'currency': 'RUB'}]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
yourArrayOfObjects.sort(function(first, second) {
 return second.price - first.price;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript isn't Python. You have an array of objects there.

Call the [array `sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Pass it a function that takes two arguments (the two objects in the array that are being compared). Have it return `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on which order you want those two objects to be sorted into (there are examples and more detail in the documentation I linked to above).